# how to determine the source application of xorg activity?

Tags: screen-lock

My screen was not auto locking after 10mins as i configured it.

Using `xssstate -i`, and w/o touching the mouse or the keyboard, i saw that every 30s the iddle timer got reset to 0.

I need to know how to determine what is resetting the timer so i can create a warning message saying the screen will not auto lock and why.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running `xinput --test-xi2 --root` to show you all the input events as they occur, but they wont show an explicit screensaver command such as from `xset s reset`.